# R ggplot2 line two rows and all columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, reshape

I have this dataset:

```
structure(list(AgeGroup = c("Old", "Young"), Point.1 = c(0.401899407258065, 
0.432845035714286), Point.2 = c(0.435610404, 0.448826385964912
), Point.3 = c(0.466951088, 0.473339649122807), Point.4 = c(0.490997664, 
0.505416649122807), Point.5 = c(0.51047508, 0.517228789473684
), Point.6 = c(0.519614064, 0.520077087719298), Point.7 = c(0.524924236, 
0.522939438596491), Point.8 = c(0.535448152, 0.523846929824561
), Point.9 = c(0.539298204, 0.529132140350877), Point.10 = c(0.546288992, 
0.535221877192982), Point.11 = c(0.552286756, 0.544069684210526
), Point.12 = c(0.548644056, 0.547988701754386), Point.13 = c(0.546028996, 
0.556100789473684), Point.14 = c(0.551464336, 0.557342807017544
), Point.15 = c(0.55835804, 0.552995140350877), Point.16 = c(0.560958056, 
0.555753035087719), Point.17 = c(0.566631508, 0.553254912280702
), Point.18 = c(0.573644824, 0.557015719298246), Point.19 = c(0.579504268, 
0.560797315789474), Point.20 = c(0.583600364, 0.560459526315789
), Point.21 = c(0.591889884, 0.563138245614035), Point.22 = c(0.598549332, 
0.578847140350877), Point.23 = c(0.605920632, 0.59655149122807
), Point.24 = c(0.612308084, 0.611475473684211), Point.25 = c(0.618838952, 
0.627695631578947), Point.26 = c(0.626865524, 0.640329719298246
), Point.27 = c(0.634642932, 0.642362438596491), Point.28 = c(0.639958892, 
0.640706877192982), Point.29 = c(0.642219468, 0.654251789473684
), Point.30 = c(0.651740076, 0.674775824561404), Point.31 = c(0.657197604, 
0.679311385964912), Point.32 = c(0.657618572, 0.673946421052632
), Point.33 = c(0.653554616, 0.67093849122807), Point.34 = c(0.648990388, 
0.673238403508772), Point.35 = c(0.643885328, 0.669246245614035
), Point.36 = c(0.636234632, 0.670007543859649), Point.37 = c(0.632127604, 
0.667657561403509), Point.38 = c(0.631252172, 0.665906228070175
), Point.39 = c(0.637404984, 0.677649561403509), Point.40 = c(0.6451598, 
0.679067614035088), Point.41 = c(0.648019716, 0.688604824561403
), Point.42 = c(0.645375244, 0.692729175438596), Point.43 = c(0.647187664, 
0.691994543859649), Point.44 = c(0.651923432, 0.681522859649123
), Point.45 = c(0.650062976, 0.674073456140351), Point.46 = c(0.638525956, 
0.660092263157895), Point.47 = c(0.627772732, 0.652689456140351
), Point.48 = c(0.615988064, 0.650307087719298), Point.49 = c(0.599147952, 
0.651349771929825), Point.50 = c(0.584897698795181, 0.63722649122807
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

which a subset of the 50 points looks like:

```
     AgeGroup   Point.1   Point.2   Point.3   Point.4   Point.5   Point.6   Point.7   Point.8   Point.9  Point.10  Point.11  Point.12  Point.13  Point.14  Point.15  Point.16
1      Old 0.4018994 0.4356104 0.4669511 0.4909977 0.5104751 0.5196141 0.5249242 0.5354482 0.5392982 0.5462890 0.5522868 0.5486441 0.5460290 0.5514643 0.5583580 0.5609581
2    Young 0.4328450 0.4488264 0.4733396 0.5054166 0.5172288 0.5200771 0.5229394 0.5238469 0.5291321 0.5352219 0.5440697 0.5479887 0.5561008 0.5573428 0.5529951 0.5557530
```

I am having difficulty plotting all columns on one graph, where X is just `1:50` tick marks and Y is the `value` of each point, color coded by `AgeGroup`.

I have tried melt, but I dont think thats necessary as it transposes the data and doubles the Point values.

I've tried variations of the following:

```
ggplot(YaxL,  aes(x=1:50,y=YaxL[2:51])) + geom_point()
```

and

```
   ggplot(YaxL, aes(x = 1:50)) + 
      geom_line(aes(y = YaxLDF[1,1], colour = "Old")) + 
      geom_line(aes(y = YaxLDF[2,1], colour = "Young"))
```

I feel like I'm overthinking this, help appreciated.

Comment: ggplot looks for columns in your data to map to the desired aesthetics so melting as you described is right patch to use it. If you're opposed to melting, then you could use the base plot function to explicitely pass vectors for your x and y values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this approach. You can reshape to long with `pivot_longer()` and use the `separate()` function to extract the point position. After that the design of the plot is very practical. I have used the data you shared as `YaxL`. Always first try to reshape your data and then the plots can be easily built. Here the code:

```
library(tidyverse)
#Data process and plot
YaxL %>% pivot_longer(-1) %>%
  separate(name,c('name','x'),sep='\\.') %>% 
  mutate(x=as.numeric(x)) %>%
  dplyr::select(-name) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x=x,y=value,color=AgeGroup,group=AgeGroup))+
  geom_point()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: the melt works similar to the pivot and it seems `separate` is what I was missing, thanks!